# Why is my setTimeout in (endless) while loop not working? (timer)

Tags: javascript, typescript, loops, settimeout

I wanted to write a simple timer that counted op by 1 in about one second intervals and
(not knowing about the existence of setInterval)
I wrote this:

```
let log : boolean = true;

const setLogTrue = () => {
  log = true;
};

let timer : number = 0

while (true){
    if (log == true){
        timer ++;
        console.log(timer);
        log = false;
        setTimeout(setLogTrue, 1000);
    }
}
```

Is only print out 1 and then waits forever for the log to become true again.

**Question:** Why is it not setting log back to true?

I cant figure out why my first try is not working.
I cant use the debug terminal cause i cant find where to keep track of the setInterval countdown.

> **Not the question**: How to do it.
> It can be done whit setInterval:
>
> ```
> let timer : number = 0
> const printTimer = () =>{
> timer ++;
> console.log(timer);
>
> }
> setInterval(printTimer, 1000);
> ```
>
> or by using setTimeOut in a different way:
>
> ```
> const printTimer = () => {
> console.log(timer++);
> setTimeout(printTimer, 1000);
> }
> printTimer();
> ```
>
> That I know now.

I read [In a While loop setTimeout not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44486075/21332421).
But that answers a different problem regarding loops and timeout
being: timeout does not pauze the rest of your code.

Does anyone know we I got it wrong? =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you have a `while (true)`.

JavaScript runs on a single thread. Asynchronous callbacks from things like `setTimeout` or HTTP Requests are placed on a queue, and picked up once the execution thread isn't actively doing anything. Since your initial `while` loop never completes, that execution thread never gets released, so there's never an opportunity for your timeouts to fire.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is commonly executed single threaded which means that your while loop

```
enter code here

while (true){
   if (log == true){
     ...    
   }
}
```

is never exited which means that the timer callback is never executed.